# How can I connect my laptop to WiFi?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, lenovo

My Lenovo G480 does not detect my wireless network when I'm running Ubuntu, but it has no problem in Windows 7. When I boot with Ubuntu, it immediately displays a message saying "You are disconnected." and when I try to check for wireless networks, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: sudo service network-manager restart , try this

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have this particular model laptop, I did a little research and found the following [Link to UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050126) I have listed the relevant commands below....

Connect to the internet using a wired connection.
Type the following to get to a terminal CRTL T  (hold down the ctrl key and hit t)
copy/paste the commands, one line at a time into the terminal window.
reboot and try a WIFI connection.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.5/compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc.tar.bz2
tar -xf compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-3.5.1-1-snpc
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```